kcf_tracking window does not open for depth camera to come on
I am a Python code for a robot vehicle to track an object using the kcf_tracking. However, the kcf_tracking window pops up small and gets stuck. I am not able to see the camera to identify the object to track. My python code works well. I am run on ros-melodic. Is there any other packages to install? Running the code with debugging statement. The code get stuck at "print("KCFNode initialization complete.")"
the code
import cv2
import rospy
import numpy as np
import jetauto_sdk.pid as pid
import jetauto_sdk.fps as fps
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist

class KCFNode:
    def __init__(self, name):
        print("Initializing KCFNode...")  # Debug statement
        rospy.init_node(name)
        self.name = name
        self.pid_d = pid.PID(1.8, 0, 0)
        
    self.pid_angular = pid.PID(0.005, 0, 0)
    self.go_speed, self.turn_speed = 0.007, 0.04
    self.linear_x, self.angular = 0, 0

    self.fps = fps.FPS()
    
    self.DISTANCE = 50
    self.distance = self.DISTANCE
    self.mouse_click = False
    self.selection = None
    self.track_window = None
    self.drag_start = None
    self.start_circle = True
    self.start_click = False
    self.depth_frame = None

    # Try creating tracker
    print("Creating KCF tracker...")  # Debug statement
    self.tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
    # self.tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()
    
    fs = cv2.FileStorage("custom_csrt.xml", cv2.FILE_STORAGE_READ)
    fn = fs.getFirstTopLevelNode()
    self.tracker.read(fn)

    cv2.namedWindow(name, 1)
    cv2.setMouseCallback(name, self.onmouse)
    
    camera = rospy.get_param('/depth_camera/camera_name', 'camera')
    self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber(f'/{camera}/rgb/image_raw', Image, self.image_callback, queue_size=1)
    self.depth_image_sub = rospy.Subscriber(f'/{camera}/depth/image_raw', Image, self.depth_image_callback, queue_size=1)
    self.mecanum_pub = rospy.Publisher('/jetauto_controller/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=1)
    rospy.sleep(0.2)
    self.mecanum_pub.publish(Twist())
    print("KCFNode initialization complete.")  # Debug statement

def depth_image_callback(self, depth_image):
    print("Processing depth image callback...")  # Debug statement
    try:
        self.depth_frame = np.ndarray(shape=(depth_image.height, depth_image.width), dtype=np.uint16, buffer=depth_image.data)
        print("Depth image processed with shape:", self.depth_frame.shape)  # Debug statement
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error processing depth image:", e)  # Debug statement

def image_callback(self, ros_image: Image):
    print("Processing image callback...")  # Debug statement
    try:
        rgb_image = np.ndarray(shape=(ros_image.height, ros_image.width, 3), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=ros_image.data)
        result_image = self.image_proc(np.copy(rgb_image))
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error in image_proc:", e)  # Debug statement
        result_image = rgb_image
    # cv2.imshow(self.name, cv2.cvtColor(result_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key != -1:
        self.mecanum_pub.publish(Twist())
        rospy.signal_shutdown('shutdown')
    print("Image callback processed.")  # Debug statement

def onmouse(self, event, x, y, flags, param):
    print(f"Mouse event detected: {event}, at position ({x},{y})")  # Debug statement
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        self.mouse_click = True
        self.drag_start = (x, y)
        self.track_window = None
        print("Mouse left button down - started tracking region.")  # Debug statement
    if self.drag_start:
        xmin = min(x, self.drag_start[0])
        ymin = min(y, self.drag_start[1])
        xmax = max(x, self.drag_start[0])
        ymax = max(y, self.drag_start[1])
        self.selection = (xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax)
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        self.mouse_click = False
        self.drag_start = None
        self.track_window = self.selection
        self.selection = None
        roi = self.depth_frame[self.track_window[1]:self.track_window[3], self.track_window[0]:self.track_window[2]]
        try:
            roi_h, roi_w = roi.shape
            if roi_h > 0 and roi_w > 0:
                roi_cut = [1/3, 1/3]
                if roi_w < 100:
                    roi_cut[1] = 0
                if roi_h < 100:
                    roi_cut[0] = 0
                roi_distance = roi[int(roi_h*roi_cut[0]):(roi_h - int(roi_h*roi_cut[0])), 
                                   int(roi_w*roi_cut[1]):(roi_w - int(roi_w*roi_cut[1]))]
                self.distance = int(np.mean(roi_distance[np.logical_and(roi_distance>0, roi_distance<30000)])/10)
        except:
            self.distance = self.DISTANCE
        print("Mouse left button up - tracking region selected.")  # Debug statement

def image_proc(self, image):
    print("Starting image processing...")  # Debug statement
    if self.start_circle:
        if self.track_window:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (self.track_window[0], self.track_window[1]), (self.track_window[2], self.track_window[3]), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        elif self.selection:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (self.selection[0], self.selection[1]), (self.selection[2], self.selection[3]), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        if self.mouse_click:
            self.start_click = True
        if self.start_click:
            if not self.mouse_click:
                self.start_circle = False
        if not self.start_circle:
            print("Starting tracker...")  # Debug statement
            bbox = (self.track_window[0], self.track_window[1], self.track_window[2] - self.track_window[0], self.track_window[3] - self.track_window[1])
            self.tracker.init(image, bbox)
            # cv2.imshow("Image", image)
    else:
        twist = Twist()
        ok, bbox = self.tracker.update(image)
        if ok and min(bbox) > 0:
            print("Tracking successful.")  # Debug statement
        else:
            print("Tracking failure detected.")  # Debug statement
        self.mecanum_pub.publish(twist)
    self.fps.update()
    result_image = self.fps.show_fps(image)
    print("Image processing complete.")  # Debug statement
    return 

result_image

def main():
    print("Starting KCFNode...")  # Debug statement
    kcf_node = KCFNode('kcf_tracking')
    try:
        rospy.spin()
    except Exception as e:
        kcf_node.mecanum_pub.publish(Twist())
        rospy.logerr(f"Exception in main: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


In your main(), you have not called rospy.init_node(...). This means none of the ros features will work.
